# jquery ajax goes to error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

This is my function

```
function removeMember(myElement){
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "",
    data: {
        op: "showProjectWidget.projectHandler",
        rem:myElement.rel[0],// tried also (removing this comma) same issue
    },
    success: function(data) {   
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
        location.reload();
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("Error removing Member to Project");
    }
});}
```

this is the one who calls it

```
<a href="" rel="10" onclick="removeMember(this)">(x)</a>
```

FAQ:
if i would do

```
alert(myElement.rel[0]);
```

it would return a message box with 10
so i believe that syntax is legit.

Now when I click that "(x)"
it goes to the error function. I don't know why

What am I using?

I'm using jsp
this values would be pass to a request handler

i could get them using `HttpServletRequest`.

Now my primary concern is it does not go to success function..
Any guess?

## EDIT----------

i changed `rem:myElement.rel[0]`  to `rem:$(myElement).attr('rel')` on the actual code //credits to @Felix. :) thanks

Now, it does pass the (data) and goes through my java class and do the logic thing. Yet it does not goes to the success function. It calls the error function even though the request has been completed

## SOLVED----------

i changed the html to:

```
<a rel="10" onclick="removeMember(this)">(x)</a>
```

i removed that href attribute.. although it does not have the kind of feature(the mouse pointer would be like of a hand pointing, and the text would be underlined) of a link but at least it suffices the click function.

i really don't know whats the reason behind it. but i guess its enough

Comment: Did you mean to supply a target URL for your AJAX call?  It's blank.

Comment: @intracept, i really dont use that url to pass the variable.. im using that "op:" so that the variables will be recognize by the java class

Comment: Thought as much, just checking :)

Comment: okay thanks for that info  @Medhat Gayed .. i removed it.. sorry, im just beginning to understand jquery

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
rem: myElement.rel
```

or:

```
rem: $(myElement).attr('rel')
```

instead of:

```
rem: myElement.rel[0]
```

since `myElement.rel[0]` will return `1` not `10` as what you've expected.

Comment: thanks for this! it solved the problem.. party, i guess.. it does pass the (data)
and goes through my java class and do the logic thing..
yet it does not goes to the success function.. it calls the error function even though the request has been completed